# WPF, Prism: How to access non-static method in other module?

Tags: c#, wpf, module, prism

As I understand, Prism does not keep a reference to the module instance that is created.

How do I then access non-static methods from one module in another when I cannot access the instance of the module object that is currently being used?

**Edit:** I got it working by retrieving the datacontext from the view and casting it to the model used (where the method I want is located). Not sure if this is good practice.

```
IRegionManager regionManager = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IRegionManager>();

IRegion region = regionManager.Regions["RegionName"]; ;

Module.Views.View currentView= null;
foreach (Module.Views.View view in region.ActiveViews)
{
  currentView = view;
}

var model = (Module.Model)currentView.DataContext;

mode.Method();
```

Comment: You could use the `EventAggregator` which is included in the PRISM framework to send a message from one module and receive it from the other one.

Answer (score 1):

The module definition (a.k.a. the class that implements `IModule`) does not contain any methods worth calling for anyone but the `Initialize` method that's called by the framework.

If you want to implement a method in one module and use it from another (or in the same module, that is, it doesn't matter), create a class and implement an interface.

Example:

```
public interface IMyService
{
    void MyMethod();
}

internal class MyImplementation : IMyService
{
    #region IMyService
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        // do something useful ModuleA's way
    }
    #endregion
}

internal class ModuleA : IModule
{
    public ModuleA( IUnityContainer container )
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    #region IModule
    public void Initialize()
    {
        _container.RegisterType<IMyService, MyImplementation>();
    }
    #endregion

    #region private
    private readonly IUnityContainer _container;
    #endregion
}

internal class SomeClass
{
    public SomeClass( IMyService myService )
    {
        _myService = myService;
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        // use ModuleA's method here:
        _myService.MyMethod();
    }

    #region private
    private readonly IMyService _myService;
    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 1):

EventAggregator is the best choice to communicate between modules

Comment: That depends on what you want to do. For fire-and-forget-style oneway communication, yes, but if you want an answer, I'd go for something else.

Answer (score -1):

Why can't we register the instance of the module to the container

```
public class ModuleA : IModule
{
    private readonly IUnityContainer _container;

    public ModuleA (IUnityContainer container)
    {            
        _container = container;           
    }

    #region Implementation of IModule

    public void Initialize()
    {
         _container.RegisterInstance<IModule>("ModuleA ",this);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

and get the instance in different module using

```
 var module = _container.Resolve<IModule>("ModuleA ");
```

Comment: counterquestion: why the hell would anyone ever want to do that? Use the module definition to wire up the module's part of the application. Once that is done, the module definition is no longer needed, and that's why prism does not keep references around...

Comment: Even I don't know.. why instance of module is needed.   I just responded to the question how to get the instance, but I agree, when it comes to the design it's not recommended and the best way to move to a difference class and register that one, as explained by you in the other post.